# difference between <s:Line> and graphics.lineTo()

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, drawing

If I skin a button and use the AS3 graphice.clear() and graphics.lineTo and beginFill to create a shape, the button overlaps other items in the container.

When I use the  and  mxml to create the same shape, the button is neatly positioned inside the container.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Line Object is doing a bunch of checks and extra work you aren't doing when you use the Graphics object. Look at the code for spark.primitives.Line to see what its doing that you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because Flex is unable to calculate the size of your dynamically drawn button, while the MXML version allows the size to be calculated prior to being displayed.  You may need to override the measure method to calculate the width/height.  If that's not the issue, then post some code so we can take a closer look.  Hope that helps.